# Why some applications sometimes become not "minimizable" on OS X?

Tags: macos, firefox

Sometimes for unknown circumstances to me, some applications (like Firefox) lose the minimize button.

[image: o]

What might the cause be?

Comment: Ooooh, spooky meta screenshot... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure myself but a quick Google search reveals some interesting theories:

From [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=151175):

> For some reason the OS seems to get
>   disconnected from the Dock and
>   disables the minimization. I haven't
>   found a cause yet but I usually find
>   that opening
>   /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
>   and running: Code:
>
> killall -HUP Dock
>
> fixes it. The only downside is that
>   all windows which are currently having
>   issues will not suddenly start working
>   but all new windows will behave
>   properly.

Comment: It makes sense. After your answer I put more attention on what I did. It seems like switching to a virtual machine, disconnect the application. 

New instances are fine thoug. No need to killalll.